# How to disable week days in jquery datepicker? (Enable only weekends and two specific festive days)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I´m getting mad trying this...
How to disable week days in jquery datepicker? (Enable only weekends and two specific festive days)

I tryed a lot o codes showed here and away but doesn´t work for me...

And how to disable year dropdown? Want only this current year

Can anybody help me??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to disable weekdays leaving only weekends AND add custom days (your two specific festive days). I don't know what your festive days are so I simply used 1/15/2014 and 1/16/2014 in the example below.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCJ2u/2/)

```
var availableDates = ["15-1-2014","16-1-2014"];

$(function()
{
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
      function(dt)
      { 
        return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6 || available(dt), "" ];
      }
   , changeMonth: true, changeYear: false});
});



function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Update: i removed the year dropdown as well now

Update 2:  So the reason all your previous attempts were not working is that you have a script you're including (bottom of your html file) that is applying the datepicker initialization code to every element that has class="datepicker"

This is overriding anything you try at the top of your file.  Remove the following line from your html file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://entrestaciones.es/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/datepicker.js?ver=1.8.1'></script>
```

or remove the `class="datepicker" from the input elements you dont want auto initialized

Comment: I have the follow schedule datepicker in this site:
[link]http://entrestaciones.es/prueba-formulario/
I added in header.php ur code, but still doesn´t works... :(
Btw, if u see the schedule, u can dropdown the year...i only want this current year (2014)
Thanks for ur help anyway, erikrunia!

Comment: Your code is over bloated with extra configuration options on the datepicker to a level i've never seen.  Also you are importing another script that actually automatically initializes the .datepicker call for any element that has the datepicker class attached to it.  Also when you included my sample code, you didnt change the id selector, and you have no element named #txtDate (of course).

Comment: to fix, you would need to use #input_2_5 instead of #txtDate and you would need to remove the "datepicker" class from the input field with the id input_2_5... that *should* make it work, but theres so much going on its hard to say

Comment: Thanks for ur help erikrunia!
The script u said before is only to show the months & years in spanish languaje.
Anyway, i remove it and put only ur code with #input_2_5, but still doesn´t works...what i forgive?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you didn't have to remove that.  the script i was talking about is in an included file: http://entrestaciones.es/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/datepicker.js?ver=1.8.1.  You could remove the include to that file or you can simply remove the class "datepicker" from the input_2_5 input.

Comment: once you do that, then you can add the changeMonth: true, changeYear: false into the original javascript call, I modified above in the answer so you can see what i mean

Comment: Hi again, erukrunia!
I have done destroy the default Gravity Form datepicker and loading a custom one...but now only works that doesn´t appear the year dropdown...why selected dates in variables and weekends aren´t enabled?Thanks in advance for ur awesome help!!

Comment: okay, you destroyed the jquery object after it got created, just delete the script include at the bottom that looks like this:  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://entrestaciones.es/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/datepicker.js?ver=1.8.1'></script>

Comment: then forget all that destroy stuff, and only initialize the datepicker once.. you are doing it twice now that i can see in the code, thats why the day selections arent working

Comment: you have this one:           // create new custom datepicker
        jQuery("#input_2_5").datepicker({ gotoCurrent: true, prevText: '', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png', buttonImageOnly: true });

Comment: and this one:         $('#input_2_5').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
       function(dt)
       { 
        return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6 || available(dt), "" ];
       }
    });
 });

Comment: you only need the 2nd one

Comment: Hi again, erikrunia!
It´s possible to erase past weekends and show only the next weekends?(Something like "GoTocurrentWeekend" or similar)
Thanks in advance!